# How to understand the well-supported element in the $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: c-star-algebras

An element $x$ in the $C^*$-algebra $A$ is well-supported if there is a $p\in A$ with $x=xp$ and $x^*x$ invertible in $pAp$.

That is the definition, but I cannot catch the key of it. Maybe you can show me some examples, which one is well-supported, which one is not, and what is the motivation.

Comment: Is $p$ a projection? Where did you encouter this definition?

Comment: Yes,a projection p∈A,I am sorry I forget it.

Comment: Could you give some context? Where did you encouter this definition?

Comment: In the special case where $A=B(H)$, you can show that $p$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\ker(x)^\perp$, and $x$ is well-supported if and only if $x|_{\ker(x)^\perp}$ is bounded below.